# loss problem in training a multi-modal model

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0, loss-function, multimodal

I have a dataset that contains images and texts. I use the Bert model for text input and resnet50 for image input. Now When I want to train this model I get an error. please help me.

I load my data using a generator. this is my data generator function:

```py
def multi_modal_data_generator(df, labels, image_datagen, batch_size):
    .
    .
    yield {'image_input': images,
                   'input_ids': np.array(input_ids),
                   'token_type_ids': np.array(token_type_ids),
                   'attention_mask': np.array(attention_mask)}, {'output': 
    np.array(lbls)}
```

this is my model:

```py
def image_text_model():

  image_input = Input(shape=(224, 224, 3), name='image_input')

  input_ids = Input(shape=(96,), dtype=tf.int32, name='input_ids')
  token_type_ids = Input(shape=(96,), dtype=tf.int32, name='token_type_ids')
  attention_mask = Input(shape=(96,), dtype=tf.bool, name='attention_mask')

  resnet_model = ResNet50(weights='imagenet', include_top=False)
  for layer in resnet_model.layers:
        layer.trainable = False
  image_output = resnet_model(image_input)
  image_output = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(image_output)

  # Use the BERT model to extract features from the text input
  text_features = bert_model(input_ids, attention_mask, token_type_ids)['logits']

  concatenated = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate()([
      image_output,
      text_features
  ])

  # Concatenate the image features and text features
  # concatenated = Concatenate()([image_output, text_features])

  # Add a Dense layer
  x = Dense(units=128, activation='relu')(concatenated)

  # Add the output Dense layer with softmax activation for classification
  output = Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax')(x)

  # Define the model
  model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[image_input, input_ids,  attention_mask, token_type_ids], outputs=[output])
  return model
```

this is my compile and fit function:

```py
new_model = image_text_model()
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=1e-3, epsilon=1e-08, clipnorm=1.0)
loss = tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy()
new_model.fit(train_generator, epochs=2)
```

this is my error:

```
ValueError: Found unexpected losses or metrics that do not correspond to any Model output: dict_keys(['output']). Valid mode output names: ['dense_18']. Received struct is: {'output': <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:4' shape=(None,) dtype=int64>}.
```

Comment: You set `'output'` key in your dataloader, so, try setting a name in your model's output layer, ie. `output = Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax', name='output')..`

Comment: In your model definition, you've specified the output layer as output = Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax')(x). However, during training, you're referring to the output with the name 'output'.

To resolve this issue, ensure that the output specified during training matches the output defined in your model. Since you've named the output layer 'output', make sure to use this exact name either in the loss parameter of the fit() function or in the output dictionary of your generator function.